# The insert method does not work correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe where I started one dataset in ascending order and the other in descending order. But after inserting using the `insert()` method I get different output on two versions of Pandas 1.4.3 and 1.4.4+. In version 1.4.4+ data sorting is not saved, unlike 1.4.3.

Output version 1.4.4:

|  | Sorted Ascending | Sorted Descending |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **36** | 1 | 1 |
| **35** | 2 | 2 |
| **34** | 3 | 3 |
| **33** | 4 | 4 |
| **32** | 5 | 5 |
| **31** | 6 | 6 |
| **30** | 7 | 7 |
| **29** | 8 | 8 |
| **28** | 9 | 9 |
| **27** | 10 | 10 |

Output version 1.4.3 :

|  | Sorted Ascending | Sorted Descending |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **36** | 1 | 99 |
| **35** | 2 | 98 |
| **34** | 3 | 95 |
| **33** | 4 | 94 |
| **32** | 5 | 93 |
| **31** | 6 | 92 |
| **30** | 7 | 91 |
| **29** | 8 | 90 |
| **28** | 9 | 90 |
| **27** | 10 | 89 |

What am I doing wrong?

```py
data = [23, 45, 12, 67, 89, 34, 56, 78, 90, 11,
                  43, 21, 76, 88, 33, 55, 77, 99, 22, 44,
                  66, 87, 32, 54, 98, 65, 87, 10, 9, 8,
                  7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 13, 23, 34, 45,
                  56, 67, 78, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]

df = pd.DataFrame()

data_series = pd.Series(data, name='Data')

sorted_ascending = data_series.sort_values(ascending=True)
sorted_descending = data_series.sort_values(ascending=False)

df_sorted_ascending = pd.DataFrame(sorted_ascending)
df_sorted_descending = pd.DataFrame(sorted_descending)

df.insert(0, 'Sorted Ascending', df_sorted_ascending)
df.insert(1, 'Sorted Descending', df_sorted_descending)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(kind='line')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Sorted Data Plot')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I expected to get sorted data on versions higher than 1.4.3.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please review #3 and **References** in [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the order of the columns, you should reset the index of the ascending and the descending dataframes:

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame()

data_series = pd.Series(data, name='Data')

sorted_ascending = data_series.sort_values(ascending=True)
sorted_descending = data_series.sort_values(ascending=False)

df_sorted_ascending = pd.DataFrame(sorted_ascending)
df_sorted_descending = pd.DataFrame(sorted_descending)

# Reset index
df_sorted_ascending.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_sorted_descending.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Drop the newly created column
df_sorted_ascending.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
df_sorted_descending.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)

df.insert(0, 'Sorted Ascending', df_sorted_ascending)
df.insert(1, 'Sorted Descending', df_sorted_descending)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(kind='line')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Sorted Data Plot')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

| Sorted Ascending Sorted Descending |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | -0.469474 |  | 1.579213 |
| 1 |  | -0.234153 |  | 1.523030 |
| 2 |  | -0.234137 |  | 0.767435 |
| 3 |  | -0.138264 |  | 0.647689 |
| 4 |  | 0.496714 |  | 0.542560 |
| 5 |  | 0.542560 |  | 0.496714 |
| 6 |  | 0.647689 |  | -0.138264 |
| 7 |  | 0.767435 |  | -0.234137 |
| 8 |  | 1.523030 |  | -0.234153 |
| 9 |  | 1.579213 |  | -0.469474 |